# Need to streamline formulas to auto update as sheets are added

Tags: excel

So I currently have a spreadsheet for monthly reporting that has a `VLOOKUP` **for months and values**. The data is collected and reported monthly and then input into a master workbook that calculates all of the metrics to the master charts. What I have been building on is an `If(AND)` statement and then adding a new sheet every month. The formula checks columns 7 and 8 for values on each page and only uses the value in column 8 if the value in column 7 is >0.

The formula currently looks like this:

> =IF(AND(VLOOKUP($A2,December_2020!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP($A2,January_2021!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP($A2,February_2021!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP($A2,March_2021!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP($A2,April_2021!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP($A2,May_2021!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP($A2,June_2021!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE)>0),SUM(VLOOKUP($A2,December_2020!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE),VLOOKUP($A2,January_2021!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE),VLOOKUP($A2,February_2021!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE),VLOOKUP($A2,March_2021!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE),VLOOKUP($A2,April_2021!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE),VLOOKUP($A2,May_2021!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE),VLOOKUP($A2,June_2021!$A$5:$AE$62,7,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($A2,INDIRECT(INDEX(wshNamesLast,COUNTA(wshNamesLast)+RAND()*0)&"!$A$8:$AF$62"),8,FALSE))

I **need to** make sure that it **calculates the sheet automatically**. Updating the formula every month is tedious and prone to human error but adding in months for blank sheets throws off my calculations since I get reporting from two different sources for each account.

**Q:** How can I streamline this formula to allow the sheets to still calculate correctly with any number of sheets in the workbook?

Comment: test if a [3d SUMIFS](https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets) returns a value greater than 0?

Comment: Make a list of sheet names and build the vlookup using indirect(). Then just check the list of results - that if() is ungainly and will fail...